Next.JS 13+ and IE11
How can I make Next.JS 13 application to be compatible with IE11. it uses SWC and I'm not sure how to fix SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier and SCRIPT1002: Syntax error errors

I doubt I have to tell you but IE 11 hasn't been supported for two years now.  While my hate for Next.js knows no bounds it's unlikely that a dead browser can be easily supported.

Keep in mind: even microsoft doesn't  want you to use ie11 (edge emulation often doesn't work as well - great!). Most importantly, last ie doesn't support es6 not even es5 completely – I doubt you can run environments heavily relying on modern JS in ie. Frankly it is nowadays quite geeky to emulate this browser (admittedly I wasn't too enthusiastic to get it working).

Apart from (well deserved) ie bashing - you really have all hard facts on your side to argument against "legacy" ie support:

it wasn't even that relevent at it's release (surpassed by chrome)
ie11 had a lot of shortcomings regarding JS and CSS – not present in Firefox or Chrome contemporary browsers
there were no relevant "ie11" optimized websites - like in the goood ol' ie6 era where user-agents were frequently blocked (clearly invented by as...h...l...s)


So the "meta question" is, why should anyone (maybe your employer/supervisor?) expect your web application requiring modern/cutting-edge web development techniques, to "respect" irrelevant/outdated browsers? Browsers (... uhm actually just ie) that disregarded modern web developments and were frequently lagging behind and more importantly slowing down progress? Seriously, the facts are on your side ;)

@herrstrietzel You're right. IE is dead and it's not worth to support it. thanks

@A.A: at least you and your colleagues should be paid accordingly - twice the budget! This may convince clients to finally accept the irrelevance of ie;) But don't get me wrong, there certainly use cases for complicated legacy support e.g for embedded system devices  - as long as clients don't take for granted devs can easily combine ancient web-technology with cutting edge concepts - you can negotiate! ... SWC is certainly another challenge
